# Parsing string into an HTML file and recovering it with a @GetMapping

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I've created a project with a Spring Initilizr. I'm trying to parse a string into a "code.html" file and recover it with a @GetMapping. Here's the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Code</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <p th:text="${code}">
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the method:

```
@GetMapping("/code")
public ModelAndView getHTML(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("code", code.getCode());
    model.setViewName("code.html");

    return model;
}
```

(I have a seperate class for the code so code.getCode() just returns a string.)

Unfortunately, `http://localhost:8080/code` returns an empty screen. What am I doing wrong? Maybe there's an easier way to achieve the task?

Comment: The value is set elsewhere. The code doesn't work with model.addObject("code", "some_string") either. What do you mean by adding action in HTML?

Comment: Please post the whole controller class that contains your `@GetMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

i work with springboot and thymeleaft

maybe you need send only the view in the code

like this

```
    @GetMapping("/code")
public ModelAndView getHTML(HttpServletResponse response,Model model) {
model.addAtributte("key", "code");
    return new ModelAndView ("templates/code");
}
```

the model is shipped with the view

in the html try this

```
<p th:text="${key}">
```

or you can try the <th:block>
check thymeleaf documentation